# Trying to use snap.svg. "Paper" object won't work

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

No doubt the answer is very basic, but I've looked for answers and can't find any.

I've just started using snap.svg. I followed the documentation and can create objects using the Snap (s) object, but not the Paper one.

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Snap Test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 </head>
<body>

<script src="js/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/shapes.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var s = Snap("100%", "100%");
var c = s.circle(50, 50, 40);  //This appears
var k = paper.circle(100, 100, 40); //This doesn't 

$( "<p>Test</p>" ).appendTo( "body" );

});
```

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and haven't seen anything like this before. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst s.paper.circle(100,100,40) would work, its not clear why you are trying to do this. Just use s.circle(100,100,40) again.

's.paper' will just point to 's', as 's' IS the paper. Naturally this may be part of a more complex solution using different elements, but if you are starting out, there is not much reason to reference s.paper.

What may want to do at some point, is not s.paper, but c.paper. Eg grab the correct paper from some element. Even then, I've rarely known any need to do this.

A paper is just an SVG element (with wrapping), which is what Snap(x,y) creates.

If you console.log( s, s.paper, c.paper ), they will all show to be the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, paper is undefined. I assume you intended to use the paper property on the s object. For example, change...

```
var k = paper.circle(100, 100, 40);
```

to...

```
var k = s.paper.circle(100, 100, 40);
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Bobby. As I thought, stupidly obvious. Cheers.

Comment: Not sure what the point of referencing paper here at all is ?